# Warning of undefined on lookup on indexed type

Tags: typescript

I want to create a hashmap with indexable types in Typescript. This works fine, but I lack the warning that the value could be `undefined` when doing a lookup. Is there any way to get this into Typescript?

```
interface HashMap {
    [index: number]: string;
}

const exampleMap: HashMap = {
    1: "foo",
    2: "bar"
}

const noWarningHere = exampleMap[3];

console.log(noWarningHere.length);
```

This gives a *TypeError: noWarningHere is undefined* in the browser console and the typescript compiler does not complain. In other cases the compiler would warn that it could be undefined and that I have to create a guard first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell TypeScript that the properties of `HashMap` can be `undefined`:

```
interface HashMap {
    [index: number]: string | undefined;
}
```

According to your initial definition, they couldn't. In fact, if in your example you do this:

```
exampleMap[4] = undefined;
```

You get an error, saying that `undefined` is not assignable to `string`;

Comment: Thanks, easy and very useful solution :)